# Raw http server: send image issue

Tags: c, http, http-headers, iot

I'am working with kind of IoT device. Finaly I've got simple httpd server to work, and simple html pages works like a charm, but browser does not recognise images. I think this is http header issue, but i do not know what is exacly wrong.

For example, my test page look like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>test page</title></head>
<body>
hello world!
<img src="img.png">
</body>
</html>
```

If i go to http://de.vi.ce.ip/ 2 reqests are generated:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
Accept text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*\r\n
Accept-Language: en-EN\r\n
...

GET /img.png HTTP/1.1\r\n
Accept image/png, image/svg+xml, image/*;q=0.8, */*;q=0.5\r\n
Accept-Language: en-EN\r\n
...
```

To witch my server responds with:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n
Content-Type: text/html\r\n
Content-Length: 131\r\n
\r\n
<page data>

HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n
Content-Type: image/png\r\n
Content-Length: 5627\r\n
\r\n
<image binary data>
```

As the result i can see the text, but images are broken.
I've tryed few more parameters like `Connection: close, Accept-Ranges: bytes, Content-Location (path)`.
I've tryed jpeg image under `Content-Type: image/jpeg` with no luck. I'am certain that image sent correctly.

Comment: You have to send the correct `Content-Type`. i.e. image/jpeg

Comment: @Holger I did. It is typo in my question, sorry. And it is image/png in my case.

Comment: I think you read the png from file. Do you open the file in binary mode?

Comment: @Holger Yes. I've check output buffer, before send it to tcp and it is correct. Binary content looks as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made exactly the same - raw http server for IoT and your response looks absolutely correct. Try check following:

- You correctly flush the socket before closing it. If you call `close()` right after send(), you will likely encounter this problem - data has not been correctly written
- The Content-Length should be exactly the size of your file. Make sure you are not counting \r\n bytes of http response. Browser may still wait for tail bytes
- Finally, get the browser network logs :)

Comment: Turns out it was memory problem. The tcp_write function returned -1 witch is memory error. I use lwip and it is based on it's own wierd alloc functions. I've just increased buffer sizes and it worked. There is no flush function, but there is tcp_output function, witch forces sending data, but it did not help. Also i've tryed to write data in chunks, but result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

The request is asking for `png`

```
GET /img.png HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

Why not return the correct content type;

```
Content-Type: image/png\r\n
```

Comment: Sorry it was typo in question. I am sending correct content-type image/png for png or image/jpeg for jpg.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a very similar problem.

In my case when I thought I was using `\r\n` line terminators, I was actually only using `\n`; which worked fine in chromium for serving the `text/html` page, but was throwing `net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE` error when serving the `image/jpeg`. So the page loaded, but the images were broken.

My fix was to make sure that everything was using `\r\n` as it was supposed to.